# Equation of the straight line equidistant from $(2,-2)$ & $3x - 4y + 1 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried this as:
$$\sqrt{(2 - h)^2 + (k + 2)^2} = \dfrac{3h - 4k + 1}{5}$$ where $(h,k)$ is the point on the required straight line. But on expanding, the equation contains terms of $h^2$ & $k^2$ which isn't possible as equation of st.line must be linear. So, is my way wrong? What is the correct way?? Please help.

[Answer is $6x - 8y = 13$]

Comment: Does the question ask for a straight line, or just an equation?

Comment: @abiessu a straight line is given by an equation only like $x+y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done will result in a parbola which is defined as equidistant from a fixed line $ax+by+c=0$ and a fixed point $(x_1,y_1)$, the general equation of which is:
$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}=\frac{|ax-by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Let's use a naming $L_g$:given line, $L_f$: line to be found, $P$: the givenpoint

**You were required to use distance between $L_f$ and $P$ (which is actually the distance between foot of perpendicular on $L_f$ and $P$), not distance between any point on $L_f$ and $P$.**

The resulting line will also be parallel to already given line.See given figure, blue line is what we have, red point is what we have, now, the green curve is what you predicted and the the purple line is what we want, this line might look parallel, but before starting think it's not parallel, so these lines must intersect somewhere and thus the distance between them is $???$ (think), (that makes it necesarry to have both lines parallel)
[image]

Comment: Sir,why is my approach wrong?? And why is the line must be parallel to the given line?? Suppose,you measure the length from the given point and the line questioned, then...

Comment: @user36790 think this: how is distance between two lines measured? or what is "distance betweeen two lines"?

Comment: Sir, suppose the given line isn't parallel to the required line but its distance from (h,k) is same as that from (h,k) to (2,-2). Then sir?

Comment: @user36790 see edit in my answer (and don't use sir, I have a display name)

Comment: @user36790 further edited

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The required straight line has to be parallel to $3x-4y+1=0$

So, the distant of the required straight line from

$(i)(2,-2)$ and

$(ii)$ any point on  $3x-4y+1=0,(1,1)$(say)

have to be same

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Imagine the situation pictorially. Draw a perpendicular from $(2,-2)$ on the line $3x-4y+1=0$. The required straight line must pass through the midpoint of this segment.

Now you have a particular point on the required line and you know its slope.

Answer (score 0):

Required line equation must be $'\ldots 3x-4y+c=0$. The distance of the point $P=(2,-2)$ to the line $d\ldots 3x-4y+1=0$ is $3$ so the point $P$ will be distance $\frac{3}{2}$ to $d'$. So it must be
$$ \frac{3}{2}=\frac{|3\cdot2-4\cdot(-2)+c|}{5}. $$
After simple calculations $c$ is $-\frac{13}{2}$ or $-\frac{43}{2}$. $(1,1)$ is a point of the line $d$. Distance from $(1,1)$ to $d'$ must be $\frac{3}{2}$ so
$$ \frac{3}{2}=\frac{|3\cdot 1-4\cdot 1+c|}{5}. $$
From this equation we get $-\frac{13}{2}$ and $\frac{17}{2}$ for $c$. So $c=-\frac{13}{2}$ and  $d'\ldots $6x-8y-13=0$.

Answer (score 0):

the line through $(2, -2)$ and perpendicular to the line $3x - 4y + 1 = 0$ has the parametric form: $$x = 2 -3t, y = -2 + 4t.$$  you find the particular time $t,$ this point is on the line is given by $3(2-3t) - 4(-2+4t) + 1 = 0.$ this gives you $t = 3/5.$ now if you in the other direction for $3/5$ you end up at the point $(2 + 9/5, -2 - 12/5).$ the line through this point and parallel to $3x - 4y = 1$ is $$3x - 4y = 6 + 27/5 + 8 + 48/5 = 29.$$